# Issue when printing out from a CSV file. It prints out an address instead of what it is in the CSV file. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: java, csv

I need to print out from a CSV file the information that is in it. The problem is that i need to use a Parser Class who will be responsible for formatting the object into the attributes of the "bean". When i try running it, it prints out an address, instead of the information that is in the CSV file. The classes that i'm using  to do that are below. I think the issue might be in method"public T readObject();' however i dont know how to fix it. I've added toString(), as well, however, it did not work. 
There are screenshots attached as well.

```
    package com.senac.leituradearquivos;



public class Paciente {

    private String nome;
    private String rg;
    private String dataNascimento;

    public Paciente(String nome, String rg, String dataNascimento) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.rg = rg;
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public Paciente() {

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(String dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

}

package com.senac.leituradearquivos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PacienteParser implements CSVParser<Paciente> {

    // dados = "Tammy Lawrence;402750779;1998-10-05"
    // Paciente?

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public Paciente parseObjects(String dados) {

        Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(dados);
        leitor.useDelimiter("[;\n]");

        while (leitor.hasNext()) {

            paciente.setNome(leitor.next());
            paciente.setRg(leitor.next());
            paciente.setDataNascimento(leitor.next());

        }

        return paciente;
    }













}


  package com.senac.leituradearquivos;

public interface CSVParser<T> {

    public T parseObjects(String dados);

}

    package com.senac.leituradearquivos;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSVFile<T> {

    private CSVParser<T> objectParser;
    private FileReader fr;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void open(String filename) {

        try {

            fr = new FileReader(filename); // abriu o arquivo
            Scanner leitor = new Scanner(fr); // leu arquivo
            leitor.useDelimiter("[;\n]");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

            System.err.println(fnfe.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void close() throws IOException {

        fr.close();

    }

    public T readObject() {

        // le uma linha do arquivo
        // chamar o parse para converter os dados no objeto apropriado

        // PacienteParser nParser = new PacienteParser();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(fr); // leu arquivo
        leitor.useDelimiter("[\n]");

        return objectParser.parseObjects(leitor.next());

        // nParser.parseObjects(leitor.next());

        // return (T) objectParser; // return T precisa retornar um tipo
        // genérico
    }

    public void setParser(CSVParser<T> parser) {

        this.objectParser = parser;

    }

}


 package com.senac.leituradearquivos;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PacienteParser paciente = new PacienteParser();

        CSVFile<Paciente> file = new CSVFile<>();

        file.open("pacientes.csv");

        file.setParser(paciente);
        System.out.println(file.readObject());

        file.close();




    }

}
```

Example:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJYFH.jpg)

[CSVFile Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4olD.jpg)

Comment: can i see your csv file ?

Comment: Of course, How could i send it to you? The first lines of my CSV file are:
#fields:  name;RG;dataNascimento
Tammy Lawrence;402750779;1998-10-05
Lilian Cline;629825901;1931-02-10
Mosley Solis;207143692;1987-12-20
I think i need to add a loop somewhere but i don't know how, i've tried in my main, in the readObject() method, however, it doesn't work.

Comment: System.out.println(file.readObject()); 
here it will invoke the toString() method of your object,

try casting it to Paciente , and print what you want like name or whatever

Comment: I've tried that already, doesn't work either. It prints out : Paciente [nome=#fields:  name, rg=RG, dataNascimento=dataNascimento]. The first line of the CSV, there are like 1k lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir Go through this . it would help you a lot.
csv file used is : 
Tammy Lawrence1;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence2;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence3;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence4;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence5;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence6;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence7;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence8;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence9;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence10;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence11;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence12;402750779;1998-10-05
Tammy Lawrence13;402750779;1998-10-05

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("hi");
        PacienteParser paciente = new PacienteParser();
        CSVFile<Paciente> file = new CSVFile<>();
        file.open("pacientes.csv");
        file.setParser(paciente);
        List<Paciente> pList =file.readObject();
    for(Paciente p:pList){
        System.out.println(p.getNome());
        System.out.println(p.getRg());
        System.out.println(p.getDataNascimento());
    }
        file.close();
    }
}



class Paciente {
    private String nome;
    private String rg;
    private String dataNascimento;
    public Paciente(String nome, String rg, String dataNascimento) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.rg = rg;
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public Paciente() {

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(String dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

}





class PacienteParser implements CSVParser<Paciente> {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public Paciente parseObjects(String dados) {
    Paciente paciente=new Paciente();
    String[] as=dados.split(";");
        paciente.setNome(as[0]);
        paciente.setRg(as[1]);
        paciente.setDataNascimento(as[2]);
          return paciente;
    }
}




 interface CSVParser<T> {
    public T parseObjects(String dados);
}


 class CSVFile<T> {
    private CSVParser<T> objectParser;
    BufferedReader reader ;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void open(String filename) {
        try {
            reader =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println(fnfe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        reader.close();
    }

    public List<T> readObject() {
        List<T> list=new ArrayList<>();
        String line="";
        try{
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

               T t=(T) objectParser.parseObjects(line);
                list.add(t);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void setParser(CSVParser<T> parser) {
        this.objectParser = parser;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sunil... that worked quite well.. i just had to adapt minor differences to my code.

Answer (score 0):

As System.out.println(file.readObject()); will print the reference of the object as readObject return type is object.
You can remove main method from PacienteParser and amend you TestApplication class following to print the Paciente Object.

```
public class TestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PacienteParser paciente = new PacienteParser();

    CSVFile<Paciente> file = new CSVFile<>();

    file.open("pacientes.csv");

    file.setParser(paciente);
    Paciente p =file.readObject();
    System.out.println(p.getNome());
    System.out.println(p.getRg());
    System.out.println(p.getDataNascimento());
    file.close();
}
```

Output is  :

Tammy Lawrence
402750779
1998-10-05

Comment: nopes, the output was #fields:  name
RG
dataNascimento which is the first line of my csv file. I need to find  a way to print everything from my CSV file. There must be like 200 lines there